# java string.getBytes("UTF-8") javascript equivalent

Tags: java, javascript, utf-8, byte, utf-16

I have this string in java:

```
"test.message"

byte[] bytes = plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8");
//result: [116, 101, 115, 116, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101]
```

If I do the same thing in javascript:

```
    stringToByteArray: function (str) {         
        str = unescape(encodeURIComponent(str));

        var bytes = new Array(str.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i)
            bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);

        return bytes;
    },
```

I get:

```
 [7,163,140,72,178,72,244,241,149,43,67,124]
```

I was under the impression that the unescape(encodeURIComponent()) would correctly translate the string to UTF-8. Is this not the case?

Reference:

http://ecmanaut.blogspot.be/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*JavaScript* has no concept of character encoding for *String*, everything is in *UTF-16*. Most of time time the value of a `char` in *UTF-16* matches *UTF-8*, so you can forget it's any different.

There are more optimal ways to do this but

```
function s(x) {return x.charCodeAt(0);}
"test.message".split('').map(s);
// [116, 101, 115, 116, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101]
```

So what is `unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))` doing? Let's look at each individually,

1. [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is converting every character in `str` which is illegal or has a meaning in *URI Syntax* into a *URI escaped* version so that there is no problem using it as a key or value in the search component of a *URI*, for example `encodeURIComponent('&='); // "%26%3D"` Notice how this is now a 6 character long *String*.
2. [`unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) is actually depreciated, but it does a similar job to `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent` (the reverse of `encodeURIComponent`). If we look in the [**ES5 spec**](http://es5.github.io/#B.2.2) we can see `11. Let c be the character whose code unit value is the integer represented by the four hexadecimal digits at positions k+2, k+3, k+4, and k+5 within Result(1).`
   So, `4` digits is `2` bytes is *"UTF-8"*, however as I mentioned, all *Strings* are *UTF-16*, so it's really a *UTF-16* string limiting itself to *UTF-8*.

Comment: I cannot forget it's any different as I need support for chinese.

Comment: btw if you read this they suggest unescape(encodeUricomponent()) to get utf8 value from utf16: http://ecmanaut.blogspot.be/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html

Comment: So, is there a solution?

Comment: @Wesley I should have actually tested your code; I can't actually reproduce the "wrong" result you go, I get the same as you expected, and when I try to reverse your weird output I get `"£H²Hôñ+C|"`

Comment: Are you serving the page as _UTF-8_? I'm starting to think maybe you're serving the page in a different character encoding which doesn't support all your characters and then want to convert the malformed strings in that into _UTF-8_. (This will be exceedingly difficult as the browser does a _Stream -> String (in Stream's encoding) -> UTF-16_ conversion before _JavaScript_ sees it.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Headers were being overwritten.

Comment: Incorrect, JavaScript spec uses UCS-2 which is similar to UTF-16 but does not behave the same all the time. See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding and https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode for excellent discourses on the matter

Answer (score 19):

You can use `TextEncoder` which is part of the [Encoding Living Standard](http://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/).  According to the [Encoding API](http://www.chromestatus.com/features/5714368087982080) entry from the Chromium Dashboard, it shipped in Firefox and will ship in Chrome 38.  There is also a [text-encoding](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) polyfill available.

The JavaScript code sample below returns a `Uint8Array` filled with the values you expect.

```
var s = "test.message";
var encoder = new TextEncoder();
encoder.encode(s);
// [116, 101, 115, 116, 46, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101]
```

Comment: And, then to get the total bytes, like Java's `.getBytes()`? Add values in array? i.e. `Array.from(new TextEncoder().encode('some delicious cookie')).reduce((acc, current) => acc + current, 0)`

Comment: This answer is from 2014 and should be updated to note that a polyfill is no longer needed and the api is supported on all current browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder