# JavaScript equivalent of Java's String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

Tags: javascript, java, character-encoding, graalvm, graaljs

I have the following Java code:

```
String str = "\u00A0";
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

This outputs the following byte array:

```
[-62, -96]
```

I am trying to get the same result in Javascript. I have tried the solution posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51904484/12177456

```
function strToUtf8Bytes(str) {
  const utf8 = [];
  for (let ii = 0; ii < str.length; ii++) {
    let charCode = str.charCodeAt(ii);
    if (charCode < 0x80) utf8.push(charCode);
    else if (charCode < 0x800) {
      utf8.push(0xc0 | (charCode >> 6), 0x80 | (charCode & 0x3f));
    } else if (charCode < 0xd800 || charCode >= 0xe000) {
      utf8.push(0xe0 | (charCode >> 12), 0x80 | ((charCode >> 6) & 0x3f), 0x80 | (charCode & 0x3f));
    } else {
      ii++;
      // Surrogate pair:
      // UTF-16 encodes 0x10000-0x10FFFF by subtracting 0x10000 and
      // splitting the 20 bits of 0x0-0xFFFFF into two halves
      charCode = 0x10000 + (((charCode & 0x3ff) << 10) | (str.charCodeAt(ii) & 0x3ff));
      utf8.push(
        0xf0 | (charCode >> 18),
        0x80 | ((charCode >> 12) & 0x3f),
        0x80 | ((charCode >> 6) & 0x3f),
        0x80 | (charCode & 0x3f),
      );
    }
  }
  return utf8;
}

console.log(strToUtf8Bytes("h\u00A0i"));
```

But this gives this (which is a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array):

```
[194, 160]
```

This is a problem for me as I'm using the graal js engine, and need to pass the array to a java function that expects a `byte[]`, so any value in the array > 127 will cause an error, as described here:

https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2118

Note I also tried the `TextEncoder` class instead of the `strToUtf8Bytes` function as described here:

[java string.getBytes("UTF-8") javascript equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861828/java-string-getbytesutf-8-javascript-equivalent)

but it gives the same result as above.

Is there something else I can try here so that I can get JavaScript to generate the same array as Java?

Comment: The difference just seems to be signed vs. unsigned bytes. Just wrap the result with `new Int8Array(`…`)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is the same in terms of bytes, JS just defaults to *unsigned* bytes.
`U` in [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) stands for “unsigned”; the signed variant is called [`Int8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array).

The conversion is easy: just pass the result to the `Int8Array` constructor:

```js
console.log(new Int8Array(new TextEncoder().encode("\u00a0"))); // Int8Array [ -62, -96 ]
```